# How to design a provably fair dyanamic between a central server and smart contract

Tags: server-side, trust

I'm looking for a good design pattern that involves a central server but (hopefully) leverages the blockchain for provable fairness.

Let's say I intend to build a system that generates math problems, such as: **2x + 5 = z**, which always include at least one variable element (in this case, **x**), and always produce some solution (**z**).

*Note: This is an over-simplified example. In reality the problems are much harder, and trivial to compute going forwards (knowing x, finding z), but difficult to do in reverse (knowing z, finding x).*

Performing the storage and generation of these problems in a smart contract would be prohibitively expensive, so instead a central server is to be used.
Given that this is the case, what is the best way to ensure a player can:

a) trust that the answer revealed by the server at the end is the right one, and

b) trust that their success will be honored, should they find the correct answer.

My current intention is to have the central server submit a hash of the random input it uses to generate the problem (**x**), and a hash of the problem's subsequent solution (**z**), to the smart contract, before a player begins. For example, if the server picks **x = 3**, and therefore calculates that **z = 11**, it sends the hash of 3 and the hash of 11 to the contract, then presents the problem to the player as **"2x + 5 = 11. What is x?"**

Then when the player is ready they can hash both their answer (hopefully 3), as well as the solution to the problem they were given (11), and submit those directly to the smart contract for confirmation.
At this point, the server can also reveal (in plain text) the input it used (3), meaning the player can:

a) verify that the hash of that input is the same as the one the server sent to the smart contract at the start, and

b) verify that that input, when applied to the problem they were given, results in the same solution (11)(and was also sent to the contract at the start)

Now I realize that with this system the server can still cheat (e.g. by sending the hashes of 4 and 11 to the contract), and the contract would lack the knowledge needed to detect that, but at least the player will always find out (e.g. if the server then reveals 4 to be the correct answer, the player will know it doesn't produce the solution of 11, or else if the server reveals 3, the player will know that that's not what the server told the contract). Likewise if the server were to send 3 and 12 to the contract, the player could immediately detect the discrepancy.

And since no one will want to play against a server that can be proven to be cheating, the server will play fair.

So my question is: Is this the optimum design pattern here? What might be improved/altered?

*Note: I realize that in order to prevent players using rainbow tables to cheat, the hashing process would need to be more robust (possibly including some seed that changes for each player after each use).*

For what it's worth, I have considered using an Oracle to generate the random input via the smart contract (though this would have to use encryption) and send that to the server. However, I don't believe this adds any trust, as the server could just as easily ignore the contract.